# Linear transformation with $T^3+I=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true or false that

> if $T:V\to V$ is linear transformation such that $T^3+I=0$, then $\dim V\geq 3$?

Comment: No, if $I$ is the identity, then $-I:V\to V$ satisfies the relation $(-I)^3+I=0$, with no assumption on the dimension of $V$.

Comment: The statement is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if $T=-I$ in any vector space, in particular in ones of dimension${}<3$, then $T^3+I=0$ will hold.

Besides, you can *never* get a lower bound on the dimension from an identity that you linear map satisfies, because in dimension$~0$ any identity you could write down will hold (as there is only one linear map).